# Map inside a map to get subarray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have the following data:

```
{
"data": {
"site": {
  "siteMetadata": {
    "siteLinks": [
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "submenu": [
          {
            "title": "test-1",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "title 2",
        "submenu": [
          {
            "title": "test-2",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "title-3",
        "submenu": [
          {
            "title": "test-3",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "title-4",
        "submenu": [
          {
            "title": "test-4",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}
}

and I am trying to map to get the submenu title. I have managed to get the first title working with the following code but I am struggling to get the map inside a map.

```
import React from "react"

const Header = props => (
<div>
    {props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => (
        <div>
            <li key={item.title}>{item.title}</li>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
)

export default Header
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you can use item.submenu[0].title if there is only one element in the submenu as in the above example. If there is more than one element in the submenu, you can use map function inside the map. It looks like: item.submenu.map(menu => menu.title)

Answer (score 5):

You can add second map function inside a first one

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = props => (
      <div>
       {props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => (
        <div key={item.title}>
            <li>{item.title}</li>
            {item.submenu.map((x)=>(
              <li key={x.title}>{x.title}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
       ))}
    </div>
)

export default Header;
```

Comment: you will need a key on the nested <li> , and ideally on the top level <div> that is being mapped

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Header = props => (
  <div>
    {props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => (
        <div key={`${item.title}-${key}`}>
          <h4>{item.title}</h4>
          {item.submenu && item.submenu.map((subitem, i) => (
            <li key={`${item.title}-${key}-${i}`}>{subitem.title}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const res = {
    data: {
      site: {
        siteMetadata: {
          siteLinks: [
            {
              title: "title 1",
              submenu: [
                {
                  title: "test-1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: "title 2",
              submenu: [
                {
                  title: "test-2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: "title-3",
              submenu: [
                {
                  title: "test-3"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: "title-4",
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  
ReactDOM.render(
  <Header siteLinks={res.data.site.siteMetadata.siteLinks} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work, just take the nested array and re-map its output again. I'd recommend using a unique key for each, rather than the title.

```
import React from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuidv4';

const Header = props => (
    <div>
        {props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => (
            <div>
                <li key={uuid()}>
                    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                    {item.submenu.map(subitem => (
                        <p key={uuid()}>{subitem.title}</p>
                    ))}
                </li>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);

export default Header;
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using random keys for react components as this leads to unnecessary rerenders

Comment: It's bad practice to use dynamically generated keys

Comment: Yeah, this is something I didn't actually realise until now. So thanks guys :) It might explain some of the performance issues I've been having myself with something.